# Speeding up Importing speed of txt files in c#

Tags: c#

So I've been trying to import all english words into my program, by using a txt file. And since there are a lot of english words it really takes a long time with my current method at the bottom below. But I've also tried out:

```
string a = words.ReadToEnd();
```

Which didn't work that well either. I've cutdown the amount of words the program has to input by using:

```
string a = words.ReadBlock(char[],0,500);
```

And since this worked just fine, I know it's not the code. So my question is how I can speed this process up, and if the string would load in instantly if I saved it in the Settings or if it had to load in for a long time aswell. Thanks for your help.

```
    public FrmMain()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        System.IO.StreamReader words = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Cyril\Downloads\words_alpha.txt");
        string line;
        int counter = 0;
        while((line=words.ReadLine())!=null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(line);
            dict[counter] = line;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    string[] dict = new string[1000000];
```

Comment: What is `listBox1`? Some kind of UI? It is extremely unlikely that it can show 1000000 lines or that, if it could, a person could read that. Only read and display lines that fit in the UI. You may be able to use some kind of virtualization but, since you haven't shown us what `listBox1` is, we can't help you do that.

Comment: _And since this worked just fine, I know it's not the code._ You appear to be saying that since reading only 500 characters didn't take long, reading in some unknown, larger amount also shouldn't take long (although, that doesn't appear to be a valid line of code). How big is the file? How many words does it contain? How long does each (complete) attempt take?

Comment: It seems that if you're reading that much data it's going to take a bit of time no matter what. The only solution I can think of is `Threading` and splitting the list into different files and each `Thread` reads a different file. I also think that you can use `While (!words.EndOfStream()) { }` and get the same output? Though, that would just help with readability

Comment: @Symon I would go with Symon's approach..

Comment: @Dour High Arch The listbox1 is just a simple ListBox from Windows Forms.

Comment: @PhiM It's about 478k words, about 4mb of data and I've never waited the whole process through.

Comment: @CyrilMoser Then before your while loop do `listBox1.BeginUpdate();` and after your loop `liatBox1.EndUpdate();`. For large insertions and deletions you need to call both methods to disable that the list is is reacting to every single item.

Comment: And is there a way to just save the array in my programm so I don't have to read it in everytime?

Comment: Yes, you can save it to an array in memory. The best way to do that will depend on you app and how/where you need to access it. For example if this Form never closes, just create an array field at the Form level.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb , I think OP may be wanting to save it within the overall program, so once it is read in once, the file won't need to be read again upon re-running the program? (Different interpretations of the question, I assume)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb How can I do it if it closes?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Even if you're switching the device where the file isn't available?

Comment: @CyrilMoser - Then it probably gets only slightly more complicated. You might just be able to create the array at whatever class is creating/opening that form. But if you're on a device where the file isn't available, there's no way for it to access that data... it becomes impossible unless you've saved it to some intermediate file/database or something.

Comment: @ckuri This worked great, but for some reason it just stopped at "c"(I mean in the alpabet) and created a kind of infinite loop from there on starting with "a" again. And I'm saying kind of because it just sets your position up again to the original if you stop scrolling.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb So it'll probably be easier for me to just save it on my file then and not in my program. Thanks!

Comment: @CyrilMoser - Programs won't save anything to themselves. Any data that you want to persist between devices/executions need to be written/serialized in one form or another. Not sure if that clarifies anything, just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Oh ok, well you probably already guessed I'm new to programming, it just got me confused because of the settings, where I thought you could save data on your program, but that's just another file for it self. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, technically, if you don't care about exe size, don't need to update the list with any frequency, and/or want to be evil, you could hard code a giant array of strings.....

Answer (score 2):

I benched writing and reading thousand to million random strings using a console application and got the following results :

```
One Thousand words :: To generate : 8 milliseconds, To read : 9 milliseconds
Ten Thousand words :: To generate : 14 milliseconds, To read : 7 milliseconds
Hundred Thousand words :: To generate : 73 milliseconds, To read : 12 milliseconds
One Million words:: To generate : 525 milliseconds, To read : 181 milliseconds
```

Then I tried loading them into the Win Forms List Box using the Main Thread (as done by OP) and it timed out due to long running operation hanging the main UI thread.

OP needs to use virtual view discussed in this stackoverflow question :
[C# Virtual List View in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195868/c-sharp-virtual-list-view-in-winforms)

and an example code is given here (from the above SFQ):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ListView_VirtualMode