# How to deal with 10 million rows in a winforms list or grid from an in-memory List?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, large-data

I have to build a small viewer application that can import a large archive table from a USB stick, several million row with 4 fields (two Uint64 ID's, a timestamp and an Int32 ID). The application needs to simply show the data, allow for sorting by any column and/or filtering the data by any of the fields. No grouping, no images or tree-like structures. I am at the point where I have a List in place that is filled with objects as described above.

I'm more used to server backends with web frontends where all is about lazy loading, but now I have a giant list of objects already in place (in memory), but when I tried to use a DatagridView, the performance was not acceptable at all.

Before I reinvent the wheel and implement lazy loading from my large List: how can I get a fast and responsive table/grid for my data? This must be something that is needed very often, I suppose.

Comment: 'This must be something that is needed very often, I suppose.' no not particularly - why would you think that?

Comment: I guess that you shouldn't upload all data to ram as once

Comment: also read this; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control im used to wpf so i cannot advise on winforms. I'd check out any libraries online because there should be something there already.

Comment: @sommmen Maybe not in your field of work, but having a large pile of data from which you want to extract relevant information seems not that exotic to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Virtual List View in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195868/c-sharp-virtual-list-view-in-winforms).  Win32 has had this for [sometime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-virtual-list-view-controls) now and the feature was included in WinForms.   Essentially you tell the control it is in _virtual_ mode showing millions; you maintain a cache, and Windows simply pings you when it needs to show a visible row.  It's very memory-efficient

Comment: ...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks, MickyD, that sounds promising. Seems like virtual mode is lazy loading in Winforms speech.

Comment: No problem good sir. Hehe indeed.

Comment: I suggest to check out ObjectListView.
http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html

Specifically the `FastObjectListView` or the `VirtualObjectListView`  which are designed for speed and loading of large datasets.  The documentation talks of 10m rows!

Comment: @Alex now you're talking about extracting relevant data, whilst first you were talking about displaying that data. Im saying its rare that you need to have  a list that contains huge amounts of items to display. For example the app im working on handles thousands of db entities and displays them in a way, however we show results by day, or group based on a data query so the output always is manageble. The larges display we have at on time could be like 1000 or so items - but most ui fx handle that okay oout of the box. Just saying its rare that you actually display large amounts of data